# How to search and order filenames in a .csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have two files `A.csv` and `B.csv` , containing a list of filenames in the first column and a numeric value in the second column. The filenames listed in both the .csv files should be the same (sometimes some of the filenames in A is missing in B, but filenames in B are always present in A), but they are in a different order, while the numeric value of each filenames is different. The number of filenames in the files can be in the range 90k-200k.
An example of how the two files may look like is the following:

```
cat A.csv
a          -7.8
b          -13.1
c          -0.1
d          -3.5

cat B.csv
b          3.149
c          0.197
a          14.263
```

I will need to compare the two values for each filename, using different methods, thus it would be useful to have a new file which should look like this:

```
cat newfile.csv
a          -7.8          14.263
b          -13.1         3.149
c          -0.1          0.197
d          -3.5
```

What is the easiest way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

This does the job on python3 (tested on a jupyter notebook):

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.read_csv("A.csv",delimiter='          ',names=['name','value'])
B = pd.read_csv("B.csv",delimiter='          ',names=['name','value'])
merge = pd.merge(A, B, on='name', how='left')

display(A)
display(B)
display(merge)
```

result:

```
    name    value
0   a       -7.8
1   b       -13.1
2   c       -0.1
3   d       -3.5

    name    value
0   b       3.149
1   c       0.197
2   a       14.263

    name    value_x     value_y
0   a        -7.8       14.263
1   b        -13.1      3.149
2   c        -0.1       0.197
3   d        -3.5       NaN
```

And if you want to save the merged dataframe you can add:

```
merge.to_csv('merge.csv', sep='\t')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It looks great, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for me. It seems to only copy the values from  A.csv  in the new  merge.csv, but values from B.csv  are not merged. For some reason in the "value_y" column I only get a list of NaN. Any idea why this is happening? I changed "display" with "print" in my code, because display didn't work, and with print I can definitively see the correct values in both  A.csv  and  B.csv , but not in  merge.csv

Comment: Interestingly, I found that if I change "how='left'" to "how='right'", then the value_y column is merged correctly, but the value_x column become a list of NaN. Something seems to be wrong with this. Any suggestion?

Comment: I should have mentioned that this was tested on a jupyter notebook, that's why I can use display. 
This is really strange, are you using python 3 as well ? my gut feeling is that importing with multiple spaces as delimiter is not very good, could you try to use a standard delimiter for your csv files (like a comma) and change the delimiter accordingly.
If this doesn't work it would be nice if you could edit your question and add every input/output, so I can track the issue.